# Set specific input for some EditTexts and showing the results on Button click in TextView in Android

Tags: android, input, android-edittext, textview, onclicklistener

I'm trying to make a quiz with 5 EditTexts and a Button in Android. After clicking the Button with onClickListener I want to show the right or wrong answer in TextView or Image under each of the EditTexts with specific colors.

What is in my mind for codes is as follows:

EditText1 => set specified input (userInput.contains("elephant"))
EditText2 => set specified input (userInput.contains("lion"))

Set onClickListener for Button => *If EditText1 Contains "elephant" => textView1 set text: Correct! Else: set text: Wrong! Try again!

*If EditText2 Contains "lion" => textView2 set text: Correct! Else: set text: Wrong! Try again!

I want to have all edittexts answers in a textview for each of them in one button click.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what have you done already?

Comment: good luck with your homework assignment!

Comment: My wishes are with you, for your bright future. But have you done or tried anything to achieve what you are talking.

Comment: Thanks my friends. I found the solution after thinking a little. But I have a little question with edittext input. When I set userInput.contains("apple"), when I type "appl" that's ok, but when I type "appleeeee", because it contains "apple" in it, shows it as a correct answer. The question is: How to limit input just for the word apple? not anything more than than these five letters?

Comment: contains()- It Returns true if this string contains the characters from the given CharSequence eg "apple". If you wanna match the content or string, why don't you use equals() or equalsIgnoreCase().

Comment: Thank you A.R. Your last comment really helped. Now I use both of them in different circumstances. "Equals()" considers cases so I use it when case-sensitivity is important and use "equalsIgnoreCase()" when no matter user enters "Apple" or "apple", so ignores the case. Thanks as big as the world A.R.